# Intersection of multiple arrays without for loop in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, vectorization, intersection

I've always been told that almost all for loops can be omitted in MATLAB and that they in general slow down the process. So is there a way to do so here?:

I have a cell-array (`tsCell`). `tsCell` stores time-arrays with varying length. I want to find an intersecting time-array for all time-arrays (`InterSection`):

```
InterSection = tsCell{1}.time
for i = 2:length{tsCell};
    InterSection = intersect(InterSection,tsCell{i}.time);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), assuming there are no duplicates within each cell of the input cell array -

```
[~,~,idx] = unique([tsCell_time{:}],'stable')
out = tsCell_time{1}(accumarray(idx,1) == length(tsCell_time))
```

Sample run -

```
>> tsCell_time = {[1 6 4 5],[4 7 1],[1 4 3],[4 3 1 7]};

>> InterSection = tsCell_time{1};
for i = 2:length(tsCell_time)
    InterSection = intersect(InterSection,tsCell_time{i});
end
>> InterSection
InterSection =
     1     4

>> [~,~,idx] = unique([tsCell_time{:}],'stable');
out = tsCell_time{1}(accumarray(idx,1) == length(tsCell_time));
>> out
out =
     1     4
```

Comment: @Jonas Would you be kind enough to report on the runtime improvement you might be getting at your end with your actual data, if you happen to benchmark? I would be interested in knowing about those numbers. Thanks!

Comment: I run a small sample of tsCell_time containing three different time arrays (each with an entry length of around ~ 20000). The elapsed time of your improved solution was 0.017398 seconds vs. the 0.019724 from the "original".

Comment: just run it again with a similar set. This time 0.017 vs 0.021

Comment: @Jonas Hmm, I was expecting better numbers with the vectorized solution. Thanks for getting those!

Comment: @Jonas: With only three arrays the loop does three iterations, which is an overhead you can ignore. You have to get rid of loop doing many iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way. This also assumes there are no duplicates within each original vector.

```
tsCell_time = {[1 6 4 5] [4 7 1] [1 4 3] [4 3 1 7]}; %// example data (from Divakar)
t = [tsCell_time{:}]; %// concat into a single vector
u = unique(t); %// get unique elements
ind = sum(bsxfun(@eq, t(:), u), 1)==numel(tsCell_time); %// indices of unique elements
    %// that appear maximum number of times
result = u(ind); %// output those elements
```

Comment: I assume your solution is gonna be faster, because you omit accummary - I'll try to look at the elapsed time at some point :)

Comment: @Jonas You can also experiment with `histc(idx,1:max(idx)` instead of `accumarray(idx,1)`.

Comment: Interestingly, @Divakar solution is a lot faster (the bsxfun solution takes around a minute) - histc performs equally to accumarray.

Comment: @Jonas You might have confused `accumarray`, which is a vectorized way with `arrayfun`/`cellfun`, which are just wrappers to for-loops.