# How to find common elements in string cells?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, set-intersection

I want to find the common elements in multiple (>=2) cell arrays of strings.

A related question is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125711-how-can-i-find-the-common-elements-of-2-cell-arrays-of-strings), and the answer proposes to use the function `intersect()`, however it works for only 2 inputs.

In my case, I have more than two cells, and I want to obtain a single common subset. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
c1 = {'a','b','c','d'}
c2 = {'b','c','d'}
c3 = {'c','d'}
c_common = my_fun({c1,c2,c3});
```

in the end, I want `c_common={'c','d'}`, since only these two strings occur in all the inputs.

How can I do this with MATLAB?

Thanks in advance,

**P.S.** I also need the indices from each input, but I can probably do that myself using the output `c_common`, so not necessary in the answer. But if anyone wants to tackle that too, my actual output will be like this:

```
[c_common, indices] = my_fun({c1,c2,c3});
```

where `indices = {[3,4], [2,3], [1,2]}` for this case.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like there is code to do this on File Exchange at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6144-mintersect-multiple-set-intersection.

Comment: It looks like a straightforward sequential intersection of a pair of cells, but this is not particularly efficient as the author also noted.

Comment: @edwinksl Thank you so much! This does the trick, and for my case efficiency is not a very big concern. So if you'd like to post this as an answer, I will accept. Thanks again :)

Comment: Closely related one with numbers instead of strings : [`Intersection of multiple arrays without for loop in MATLAB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825435/intersection-of-multiple-arrays-without-for-loop-in-matlab).

Comment: @HalilPazarlama No problem. I suspect Divakar's solution will be faster though.

Answer (score 4):

Listed in this post is a vectorized approach to give us the common strings and indices using `unique` and `accumarray`. This would work even when the strings are not sorted within each cell array to give us indices corresponding to their positions within it, but they have to be unique. Please have a look at the sample input, output section* to see such a case run. Here's the implementation -

```
C = {c1,c2,c3};  % Add more cell arrays here

% Get unique strings and ID each of the strings based on their uniqueness
[unqC,~,unqID] = unique([C{:}]);

% Get count of each ID and the IDs that have counts equal to the number of
% cells arrays in C indicate that they are present in all cell arrays and
% thus are the ones to be finally selected
match_ID = find(accumarray(unqID(:),1)==numel(C));
common_str = unqC(match_ID)

% ------------ Additional work to get indices ----------------

N_str = numel(common_str);

% Store matches as a logical array to be used at later stages
matches = ismember(unqID,match_ID);

% Use ismember to find all those indices in unqID and subtract group
% lengths from them to give us the indices within each cell array
clens = [0 cumsum(cellfun('length',C(1:end-1)))];
match_index = reshape(find(matches),N_str,[]);

% Sort match_index along each column based on the respective unqID elements
[m,n] = size(match_index);
[~,sidx] = sort(reshape(unqID(matches),N_str,[]),1);
sorted_match_index = match_index(bsxfun(@plus,sidx,(0:n-1)*m));

% Subtract cumulative group lens to give us indices corres. to each cell array
common_idx = bsxfun(@minus,sorted_match_index,clens).'
```

Please note that at the step that calculates `match_ID` : `accumarray(unqID(:),1)` could be replaced by `histc(unqID,1:max(unqID))`. Also, `histcounts` be another alternative there.

*Sample input, output -

```
c1 = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'
c2 = 
    'b'    'c'    'a'    'd'
c3 = 
    'c'    'd'    'a'
common_str = 
    'a'    'c'    'd'
common_idx =
     1     3     4
     3     2     4
     3     1     2
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments to this question, there is a file in File Exchange called "MINTERSECT -- Multiple set intersection." at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6144-mintersect-multiple-set-intersection that contains simple code to generalize `intersect` to multiple sets. In a nutshell, the code gets the output from performing `intersect` on the first pair of cells and then perform `intersect` on this output with the next cell. This process continues until all cells have been compared. Note that the author points out that the code is not particularly efficient but it may be sufficient for your use case.